# Switching output with sessions

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a bit of code where I try to make a switch program.
Meaning that I want to have one value when clicking on a button and then another if I click it again. But I just can't figure out how.
It should echo "Yes" and then "No", front and back.
Anybody here that knows how I can solve this problem? I have been trying for hours on end, practicing my PHP.

```
<?php

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if(isset($_SESSION['NO']) && $_SESSION['NO'] = true) {
        echo "No";
        $_SESSION['YES'] = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "Yes";
        $_SESSION['NO'] = true;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="CHANGE">;
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ONE session variable, like `$_SESSION['state']` then the managment of its state is simple

Comment: `=` is for assignment `==` is a comparator. Check your if staatement. For strict comparator it's `===`

Comment: Just solved it, Ill post my new code.

Answer (score 1):

Use ONE session variable, like `$_SESSION['STATE']` then the management of its state is simpler.

Also `=` is an assigment operator and `==` is for value comparison.

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // reverse the state
        $_SESSION['STATE'] = ! $_SESSION['STATE'];            
    }
} else {
    // page running for the first time so has not been submitted
    // so initialise the session
    // this will ensure you get a value output the first time the page is run
    $_SESSION['STATE'] = false;

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Current State = <?php echo $_SESSION['STATE'] ? 'YES' : 'NO'; ?></p>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="CHANGE">;
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an initial value for the session variable if it does not exist and use `1- $value` ( where $value is either 1 or 0 ) to toggle the value.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['state'] ) ) $_SESSION['state']=0;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1 - $_SESSION['state'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( isset( $_SESSION['state'] ) ){
                echo $_SESSION['state'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="CHANGE" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```